# Can I use a technique before finding its journal entry?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

Throughout Bloodstained you can find journal entries which reveal how to perform special moves known as techniques. For example, pressing <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> with the Baselard performs [Surprise Gift](https://bloodstainedritualofthenight.wiki.fextralife.com/Surprise+Gift).

If you have the required weapon and enter the correct inputs, can you use a technique before finding its journal entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Per the [Wiki](https://bloodstained.fandom.com/wiki/Techniques#Overview)

> It is not necessary to find the bookshelf explaining the Technique in
> order to use it: the player only needs to have an appropriate weapon
> and input the command.

Anecdotally, I have accidentally performed moves using a weapon. It will execute and I can go about using the new move and not needing to "discover" it in a journal.

The primarily limitation of the move is that they are typically tied to 2-3 specific weapons. You have to master it using those specific weapons before being able to use them across the entire class of weapons.

Comment: After starting a new game, I can confirm Flashing Air Kick worked from the start with the Kung Fu Shoes. (The wiki originally listed the incorrect weapons for Flashing Air Kick and Hatchet Heel, but I've fixed it)